# why I can't run my code where is the problem of this code?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  final odd = where(list, (value) => value % 2 == 1);
  print(odd);
}

List<T> where<T>(List<T> items, bool Function(T) f) {
  var results = <T>[];
  for (var item in items) {
    if (f(item)) {
      results.add(item);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

**this kind of error show in my terminal**

lib/exercises/18-implement-where-function.dart:3:44: Error: The operator '%' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.

Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '%' operator.
final odd = where(list, (value) => value % 2 == 1);

```
void main() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  final odd = where(list, (value) => value! % 2 == 1);
  print(odd);
}

List<T> where<T>(List<T> items, bool Function(T) f) {
  var results = <T>[];
  for (var item in items) {
    if (f(item)) {
      results.add(item);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

The operator '%' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '%'

Answer (score 0):

Possible Dart analyzer is not able to infer type.
It's better to wait for the answer from the developers.

A workaround as below:

```
void main() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  final odd = where(list, (int value) => value % 2 == 1);
  print(odd);
}

List<T> where<T>(List<T> items, bool Function(T) f) {
  var results = <T>[];
  for (var item in items) {
    if (f(item)) {
      results.add(item);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

P.S.

I also encounter this issue from time to time in Dart.

On the one hand, the type is not explicitly specified (for parameter `value`) and must be inferred, on the other hand, it is not clear why it is not inferred from another type (aslo `T`), which is inferred from the value (in our case. `list`) wuth the same type parameter (`T`).

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code on https://dartpad.dev/dart, it's working though. I think there is an issue with your import classes.